# Error occurs in unit test in details method in MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I am developing an MVC application, and trying to create a unit test in it.

I have written the unit test as shown below.

```
   [TestMethod]
        public void Company_Details2()
        {
            Company oCompany = new Company();
            var result = oCompanyController.Details(97) as ViewResult;
            var Comp = (Company)result.ViewData.Model;
            Assert.AreEqual("TName", Comp.Name);

        }
```

and the Controller is as follows:

```
[SessionFilterAction]
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    Company company = db.Companies.Find(id);
    return View(company);
}
```

When I try to run the unit test it returns an error in the test method on the last line:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

As I am new to unit testing, I don't know how to write test methods for index, Create, Edit, Details and Delete methods, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many places where a NRE could occur in your code. For example the `db` variable that is used in your controller action might be null. Make sure that it is initialized. Also in your unit test you have the following call `var Comp = (Company)result.ViewData.Model;`. This could be null if there's no Company with id = 97 in your database. And then you attempt to compare the name `Assert.AreEqual("TName", Comp.Name);`. But if `Comp` is null this will throw an exception. Also in your unit test you are using some `oCompanyController` variable which is unclear where it got initialized.

The correct way to unit test some code is to unit test it in isolation. This means that your code should be written with abstractions in mind. It should not depend on actual implementations. It is unclear what the `db` variable is in your controller but it should be of some interface type (or abstract class) that you could mock in your unit test. This way you will achieve unit testing in isolation of the different layers. In this example you are unit testing a controller action, so the code in this controller should not depend on concrete classes.

Let's have an example of how your controller code might look like:

```
public class CompaniesController: Controller
{
    public readonly ICompaniesRepository repository;
    public CompaniesController(ICompaniesRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    [SessionFilterAction]
    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Company company = this.repository.GetCompanyById(id);
        return View(company);
    }
}
```

Now you could use a mocking framework such as Moq, NSubstitute or Rhino.Mocks to mock the repository in your unit test and be able to define expectations. For example with NSubstitute:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Company_Details2()
{
    // arrange
    var repository = Substitute.For<ICompaniesRepository>();
    var id = 97;
    var company = new Company();
    repository.GetCompanyById(id).Returns(company);
    var sut = new CompaniesController(repository);

    // act
    var actual = sut.Details(id);

    // assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(ViewResult));
    var viewResult = (ViewResult)actual;
    Assert.AreEqual(company, viewResult.Model);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, but I am completely unaware about ICompaniesRepository  and moq things...What are they  ?

Comment: It will nice if I get the changes which I have to made in my current code.

Comment: You expect me telling you the changes to your current code without showing your current code? What you have shown is only some small portion of code. The idea is to use an interface that will abstract all data access operations so that your controller is not tightly coupled to a specific data access provider. If you don't know what an interface is then I would very strongly suggest you reading some basic getting started tutorials in .NET/C# before getting into ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

As others have shown, its a good practice to code to the interface. Moq is a framework that helps you to make fake call to required functions, and is very simple to learn. Now i Assume that you are calling, `IRepository.Detials()`, so now,

```
[TestMethod]
SomeMethod()
{
 // This will create a fake/mock for your interface so that you can still call func. 
 // but not actual one.
  Mock<IRepository> mockedRepository= new Mock<IRepository>();

 // Here, we are making fake call but still Returns will give us the output.
  mockedRepository.SetUp(x=>x.Details()).Returns(Company Object);
  var result=controller.Action() as ViewResult;
  // Assert
}
```

Some may argue that but i didnt test Details method, for that you will write another unit test and so on.